# store values in multiple table with circular dependency in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have created Three tables with attributes are following:

Table name: `um_org_data` , attributes: `id, org_name, org_description, webdomain`

Table name: `addresses` ,  attributes: `id, offc_addr, um_org_datum_id`

Table name: `phone_nos` , attributes: `offc_ph, offc_ext, address_id`

Now I want that my organization with a name has multiple address 
means `Organization 1:M addresses` and address has multiple telephone numbers means `address 1:M telephone_no`

The code from my controllers are following:

um_org_datum.rb

```
class UmOrgDatum < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :org_description, :org_name, :webdomain, :addresses, :addresses_attributes

    has_many :addresses

      accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
    end
```

addresses.rb

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :offc_addr

  belongs_to :um_org_datum


  has_many :phone_nos

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :phone_nos
end
```

phone_no.rb

```
class PhoneNo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :offc_ph, :offc_ext

  belongs_to :address
end
```

as association with organization and addresses is working fine... but having problem in creating multiple telephone numbers.

the code for my view is as following:

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for(@um_org_datum) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span3 pull-right">
        <div class="well">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Sample text</p>
        </div> 
      </div> 

    <div class="span9">
      <%= simple_nested_form_for(@um_org_datum, :validate => true, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>


        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label">Organization Name&nbsp;</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <div class="input-prepend">
                <%= f.text_field :org_name, required: true, :autofocus => true %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label">Orgazination Description&nbsp;</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <%= f.text_area :org_description, :cols => "100", :rows => "10" %>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label">Web Domain&nbsp;</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <div class="input-prepend">
                <%= f.text_field :webdomain, required: true, :autofocus => true %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Office Address</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <%= f.link_to_add "<i class='icon-plus'></i>".html_safe, :addresses%>
                  <%= f.fields_for :addresses do |task_form| %>

                  <div class="input-prepend">

                    <%= task_form.text_field :offc_addr, :label => false, :placeholder => 'Office Address'%>

                    <div class="control-group">
                      <label class="control-label">Telephone</label>
                      <div class="controls">
                          <%= f.link_to_add "<i class='icon-plus'></i>".html_safe, :phone_nos%>
                            <%= f.fields_for :phone_nos do |task_form| %>

                            <div class="input-prepend">
                              <%= task_form.text_field :offc_ph, :label => false, :placeholder => 'Office Address'%>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-prepend">
                              <%= task_form.text_field :offc_ext, :label => false, :placeholder => 'Office Extension'%>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-prepend">
                              &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <%= task_form.link_to_remove "<i class='icon-remove'></i>".html_safe%>
                          <% end %>        
                      </div>
                    </div> 

                  <div class="input-prepend">
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <%= task_form.link_to_remove "<i class='icon-remove'></i>".html_safe%>
                <% end %>        
            </div>
          </div> 

        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label">Office Phone Number&nbsp;</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <div class="input-prepend">
                <%= f.text_field :offc_ph, required: true, :autofocus => true %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>         




        <div class="control-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <% if @um_org_datum.id == nil%>
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
            <% else %>
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Update</button>
            <% end %>
            <a class="btn" href="/um_org_data" style="text-color:black">Cancel</a>
          </div>
        </div>




<% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




<% end %>
```

Now what i want to do is that i have three tables which are circular dependent on each other.... `organization` table which has primary key that uses in `addresses` table as foreign key and has own primary key which is used in `phone_nos` table as foreign key.

I wants a form in which when click on + button under address show telephone label with + button where user can add multiple telephones against single address.. all is that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrapp your phone_nos into your addresses within the form, and not in the organization.

Change this block:

```
   <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Office Address</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <%= f.link_to_add "<i class='icon-plus'></i>".html_safe, :addresses%>
              <%= f.fields_for :addresses do |task_form| %>

              <div class="input-prepend">

                <%= task_form.text_field :offc_addr, :label => false, :placeholder => 'Office Address'%>

                <div class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label">Telephone</label>
                  <div class="controls">
                      <%= f.link_to_add "<i class='icon-plus'></i>".html_safe, :phone_nos%>
                        <%= f.fields_for :phone_nos do |task_form| %>

                        <div class="input-prepend">
                          <%= task_form.text_field :offc_ph, :label => false, :placeholder => 'Office Address'%>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-prepend">
                          <%= task_form.text_field :offc_ext, :label => false, :placeholder => 'Office Extension'%>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-prepend">
                          &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <%= task_form.link_to_remove "<i class='icon-remove'></i>".html_safe%>
                      <% end %>        
                  </div>
                </div> 

              <div class="input-prepend">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
              <%= task_form.link_to_remove "<i class='icon-remove'></i>".html_safe%>
            <% end %>        
        </div>
      </div>
```

to this one:

```
   <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Office Address</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <%= f.link_to_add "<i class='icon-plus'></i>".html_safe, :addresses%>
              <%= f.fields_for :addresses do |task_form| %>

              <div class="input-prepend">

                <%= task_form.text_field :offc_addr, :label => false, :placeholder => 'Office Address'%>

                <div class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label">Telephone</label>
                  <div class="controls">
                      <%= task_form.link_to_add "<i class='icon-plus'></i>".html_safe, :phone_nos%>
                        <%= task_form.fields_for :phone_nos do |phone_no| %>

                        <div class="input-prepend">
                          <%= phone_no.text_field :offc_ph, :label => false, :placeholder => 'Office Address'%>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-prepend">
                          <%= phone_no.text_field :offc_ext, :label => false, :placeholder => 'Office Extension'%>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-prepend">
                          &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <%= phone_no.link_to_remove "<i class='icon-remove'></i>".html_safe%>
                      <% end %>        
                  </div>
                </div> 

              <div class="input-prepend">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
              <%= task_form.link_to_remove "<i class='icon-remove'></i>".html_safe%>
            <% end %>        
        </div>
      </div>
```

For more information about accepts_nested_attributes_for check out the railscasts from ryan bates.
http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=nested+model+form

To check out the API docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Btw for such basic questions, railscasts.com was always a good point to start for me.

**UPDATE: To show all phone_nos within the addresses:**

Simple loop also through the adresses phone_nos

```
<tr> 
  <th col span="1" style="width: 200px">Office Address: </th> 
  <td> 
    <% if @um_org_datum.addresses %> 
       <% @um_org_datum.addresses.each do |i| %> 
         <%= i.offc_addr %><br/>
         <% i.phone_nos.each do |phone_no| %>
           <%= phone_no.offc_ph %><br/>
           <%= phone_no.offc_ext %>
         <% end %>
       <% end %> 
    <% end %> 
  </td> 
</tr>
```

Comment: you are good rails programmer.... and tell me one thing more.
I have done this to show all my adresses 
`<tr>
        <th col span="1" style="width: 200px">
         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Office Address:
        </th>
        <td>
          <% if @um_org_datum.addresses %> 
            <% @um_org_datum.addresses.each do |i| %>
               <b>>></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%=  i.offc_addr %><br/>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        </td>
      </tr>`
and i want to show phone numbers against addresses.

Comment: I updated my answer with your second question..is better than a comment, because of the code formatting..

Comment: you are good Man!! would u like to add me on facebook my facebook id is **wasi.rocker**